# Python: Choose number of bits to represent binary number

Tags: python, binary, bit

I am curious as to how I can change the number of bits to represent a binary number.
For example, say I want express decimal 1 to binary. I use:

bin(1) and get 0b1.

How can I get the return to say 0b01 or 0b001 or 0b0001 etc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> format(1, '#04b')
'0b01'
>>> format(1, '#05b')
'0b001'
>>> format(1, '#06b')
'0b0001'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str.zfill](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to pad the binary part:

```
def padded_bin(i, width):
    s = bin(i)
    return s[:2] + s[2:].zfill(width)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a builtin way to do this. However, since `bin` just returns a string, you could write a wrapper function which modifies the string to have the right number of bits:

```
def binbits(x, n):
    """Return binary representation of x with at least n bits"""
    bits = bin(x).split('b')[1]

    if len(bits) < n:
        return '0b' + '0' * (n - len(bits)) + bits
#
```